# When to use $rootScope on Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

If the right way to share data between controllers are using factory/service, what is the purpose of the $rootScope?

Comment: I use it for global helper functions for authorization and role checking. Also, route change handlers.

Comment: Read all about it https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 10):

### `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil

Scopes in Angular form a hierarchy, prototypally inheriting from a root scope at the top of the tree. Usually this can be ignored, since most views have a controller, and therefore a scope, of their own.

Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole app. For these, you can inject `$rootScope` and set values on it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these values will be available to the expressions attached to directives like `ng-show` just like values on your local `$scope`.

Of course, global state sucks and **you should use `$rootScope` sparingly**, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on `$rootScope`, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.

**Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.**

-- [AngularJS FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding.
you can use $rootScope in multiple places .

- global settings defined in factory and then in view you can update as per your condition. f.x layout manipulation
- you can assigned $state on run.
- you can handle error ($rootScope.$on(...)

I hope this will help.

Thanks